# JsonMappingException thrown by GAE endpoint due to missing entity key's appId

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using GAE endpoint, with Android as the client. I have one API that throws HTTP code 503 (service unavailable) caused by JsonMappingException, which apparently due to missing appId of the children entity.

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class AppUser implements Serializable {

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Key key;

@Persistent
private String username;

@Persistent
@Unowned
private Set<AppGroup> assignedGroups;

    // getters setters here
}
```

The Endpoint API

```
public AppGroup retrieveRandomGroup(AppUser appUser) {
    Set<AppGroup> groups = appUser.getAssignedGroups();
    // choose random group assigned to this user
    Random random = new Random();
    int chosenIndex = random.nextInt(groups.size());
    AppGroup randomGroup = (AppGroup) groups.toArray()[chosenIndex];
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Randomly choosing index: "+chosenIndex+", name:"+randomGroup.getName());
    return randomGroup;
}
```

When the Android client sent the request, it's processed correctly. I know this because I can see the message I printed out at INFO level. But, when the engine is trying to send the response, the JsonMappingException occured:

```
java.io.IOException: com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.what2eat.bean.EatingPlace["key"]->com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key["appId"])
at com.google.api.server.spi.response.ServletResponseResultWriter.writeValueAsString(ServletResponseResultWriter.java:187)
at com.google.api.server.spi.response.ServletResponseResultWriter.write(ServletResponseResultWriter.java:73)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:386)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:124)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:82)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key.getAppId(Key.java:280)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.get(BeanPropertyWriter.java:483)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:610)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:256)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectWriter._configAndWriteValue(ObjectWriter.java:456)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectWriter.writeValueAsString(ObjectWriter.java:393)
at com.google.api.server.spi.response.ServletResponseResultWriter.writeValueAsString(ServletResponseResultWriter.java:183)
at com.google.api.server.spi.response.ServletResponseResultWriter.write(ServletResponseResultWriter.java:73)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:386)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:124)
at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:82)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)...(length 9875)
```

I check the AppUser object in the client (before sending the request), and the key and the key's appId are present.
I printout some extra debugging when receiving the AppUser parameter to output the AppUser's key and the key's appId. The key has a value, but calling key.getAppId() throws null pointer exception.

Does anyone know what's wrong? 
Is this a problem with the key serialization/deserialization?

Answer (score 0):

The getAppId() method from the Key class does the following:

```
   public String getAppId() {
    return appIdNamespace.getAppId();
  }
```

It is very likely that in your case, the appIdNamespace is null, which is causing the error. Make sure that your appUser has been retrieved from the datastore so that your groups keys are properly set. If these keys are generated in your code, use the KeyFactory.createKey method, which will generate the appIdNamespace for you.